# Regex for values between 1 and 999 including 0 prefixed values

Tags: javascript

I want to create a regex that accepts a string like following:

DXXX HH:mm

where `XXX` is a number from 1 to 999 but it can also accept 0 prefixed numbers like 01 and 001, but it cannot accept for example 0001 where the total length > 3

`HH:mm` is the hour and minute in 24h format.

Example for accepted values: `D001 14:01` and `D999 00:00`

I have wrote the second part which is : `/^(2[0-3]|[0-1][\d]):[0-5][\d]$/`

And for the first part: `^\d{1,3}$` but this accepts `0`, `00` and `000`.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: `/(?=\d*[1-9])\d{1,3}/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's keep it simple:

```js
re = String.raw`
    ^
    D
    (                          # numeric group
        [1-9] [0-9]? [0-9]?    # 1 or 12 or 123
        |                      # or
        0 [1-9] [0-9]?         # 01 or 012
        |                      # or
        00 [1-9]               # 001
    )
    \x20  # space
    (                    # hours
        2 [0-3]          # 20..23      
        |                # or
        [0-1] [0-9]      # 00...19
    )
    :
    (                    # seconds
        [0-5] [0-9]      # from 00 to 59
    )
    $
`

re = new RegExp(re.replace(/#.*|\s+/g, ''))

console.log(re)

console.log(re.test('D001 23:11'))
console.log(re.test('D011 23:11'))
console.log(re.test('D111 23:11'))

console.log(re.test('D0 23:11'))
console.log(re.test('D00 23:11'))
console.log(re.test('D000 23:11'))
```

Comment: That's very nice, but it seems overcomplicated because you included the HH:mm part of the regex (which he already had), so it seems like the code is longer than it should. Maybe you could highlight only what you added. Also, consider adding some explanation.

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const regex = /^D(?:0\d?[1-9]|[1-9]{1,3}) [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d$/

console.log(regex.test("D001 14:01"))
console.log(regex.test("D999 00:00"))
console.log(regex.test("D000 00:00"))
console.log(regex.test("D00 00:00"))
console.log(regex.test("D0 00:00"))
console.log(regex.test("D001 00:00"))
console.log(regex.test("D01 00:00"))
console.log(regex.test("D011 00:00"))
```

Comment: `console.log(regex.test('D000 29:59')) // true`?

Comment: OP need not accept 000?

Comment: They don't: "*[...] but this accepts `0`, `00` and `000`.*"

Comment: The 5th case is wrong

Comment: @user19513069 `D0 00:00` return is `true` is correct op says he accepts `D0`

Comment: @user19513069 or if he doesn't like zero he can remove `0|` that's the special case I declared first

Comment: @TachibanaShin from the beggining: "XXX is a number from 1 to 999". I think the confusion is that at the end he says "but this accepts 0, 00 and 000", but he's referring to what's *wrong*, he actually doesn't want to accept those. But indeed, it's easy to remove that case from your code.

Comment: @user19513069 So that's it, I'll remove `0|` from my answer